# How to migrate to db on docker (Symfony)?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, migration

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.20
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        volumes:
            - "db_app:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        networks:
            - symfony
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - ./symfony/:/Users/admin/Downloads/symfony-docker-master/symfony
        networks:
            - symfony
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./symfony/:/Users/admin/Downloads/symfony-docker-master/symfony
        ports:
            - 8050:8050
        networks:
            - symfony

volumes:
    db_app:

networks:
    symfony:
```

The application starts, connects to the database via

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:123@db:3306/db
```

But when performing migrations through the console, I get the error

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddr  
  esses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

As I understand it, due to the fact that the address is specified in the connection db.

How to make migrations?

Comment: What's in the `networks` in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: `symfony` network in your case is redundant, because compose by default creates a bridge network which joins all your services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run console commands from **inside** of your php container

```
docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Comment: How can I execute this command automatically when running docker-compose up --build?

Comment: I would like an answer too

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the container name.

These can be found by running `docker container ls` on your console.

It's easier when you specify the name in your compose file like so:

```
services:
    db:
        container_name: db # This can be anything
        image: mysql:8.0.20
```